# Единый scroll для элементов ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

Имеется LinearLayout который включает в себя RecyclerView и LinearLayout (Header), сейчас RecyclerView скроллится сам по себе , а  Header остается сверху на месте.Как сделать так чтоб список RecyclerView и LinearLayout Header скроллились вместе введите сюда код?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llH"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_offset"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-add-header-to-recyclerview-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

Просто сделайте хэдер первым элементом `RecyclerView`. Для этого вам нужно реализовать поддержку разных типов ячеек в адаптере. Для этого используйте `getItenViewType()` метод адаптера.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llH"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_offset"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Насчет `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`:

Для старых api прописывается в коде:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvC);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Еще обращаю внимание, что атрибут `height` у `RecyclerView` = `wrap_content`